# Images on my self-hosted wordpress not loading

Tags: image, apache, wordpress, ubuntu, localhost

I have installed wordpress on my system, opened up port 80 etc. and set it all up. The site is fine and working now. You can access it here - prnv.in . But as you see the site doesn't load up the theme and the images properly.

The site works fine like it should, with the images etc on my home network. But not beyond that.

Additional information
OS : Ubuntu 11.10
Webserver : Apache

Comment: @SEO It's actually PRNV.in (but lowercase).

Comment: yep, reason #39 to increase my font size....age getting the better of me ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
http://localhost/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/headers/trolley.jpg
```

As you can see from the link, all your images are pointing to 'localhost' rather than the domain name. Either use explicit domain names or absolute paths to refer to your images in your theme

Answer (score 2):

your site is still setup to use localhost, which works fine on your computer but not on the world wide web. You need to go into your admin->settings->general and change the Site Address (URL) and Wordpress Adress fields.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Site & Blog URL in Settings > General Settings. Your site is fetching images from localhost but those images are not ready for www. 
The reason that your site works fine in localserver is that your site images are set on localhost.